# Handling large database with a cron job for a remote API connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, cron-task

I am newbie in Laravel and building a small project for practice.

There is one registration form and up to 100 registration done a day approx.

It return me status->pending of user.

Now my question come here that, php execution time for connection with remote Api is 30 second as per my knowledge.

Then, how can I handle the cron job in such a condition where I need to call remote api for receiving the data for every user status if it becomes "accepted" or "rejected" or still in "pending"

I am struggling with this condition and my database structure like

userId - status -  created_at - updated_at

I need to call it after 20 hours if possible for all user or every 4 hours if we cannot call them at once.

What will be the best practise to do it?

Comment: U need to use system cron (default) or laravel cron ?

Comment: Thank for your response , i am using laravel cron. i also built a handler but the problem is how i schedule it if there is daily 100 user regsitration and there are 2 api call which require time to execute and response of that api will affect the user record in server database

Comment: You don't need to include all the users on your job. You may segregate the users who are checked with the api before. For this you may introduce another coloumn like 'checked' 1, if the user record ran again api call. So that you will have only new records in the next job. I fear i understand you fully . Do i ?

Comment: yes. but I already tried that logic of flag.The problem is after 4 hour or 20 hour i need to again scan all users for status->modification. this logic will work only 1 time. if flag value change then it affects on my query. my query structure get complex with this logic n get so complicated

Comment: Why not trying like this ? Move the checked users to another table in successful verification ?

Comment: i will try that logic. can you refer me some post related to this. very thanks for your quick response.

Comment: welcome, good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For long-running tasks, two options come to my mind:

### Task Queues

Use an asynchronous [task queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues). They are designed for long-running tasks. Schedule one job for each newly registered user. Be sure to set the timeout longer than your estimated 30s. Pass the user instance to the constructor of the job and store it to an instance variable. From within the handler, just update the record directly.

### Callback

Implement a callback via http. This requires control over the remote api. When calling the remote api, you would submit a callback url, such as `https://local-app.domain/callbacks/finished-check-user/223` where 223 is the id of the user. The remote api would send a http request to the given url after it's finished processing. In your local app, have a controller handle the request, fetch the user by its id and update it with the data received from the remote api in the request body. Don't forget to make sure the request is authentic.

Does this help?

Comment: hello jsphpl , thanks for your quick response. i know a little bit about task queues but can you tell me more about briefly about callback api remote call. thanks. this information is very help full to me. got new things in my brain box.

Comment: Okay so the concept is two systems passing information to each other via http requests. Here is an article explaining the principle in a bit more detail: https://dzone.com/articles/rest-callbacks. Implementing it in Laravel means basically having a route/controller to receive requests, just as from your user's browser or regular api calls. For making requests, you could use `Guzzle` for example.